# package.R cant be resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

Context: I just created a react-native project, and I'm working android native side.
The fact is I cant import resource from my package like import my.package.R.
Autocompletion only allow me to import R from android.R
I already, `build -> clean -> rebuild`, and even invalidate cache etc..
My R.java is generated.

I run out of idea

Update: 
I have found something weird imo.

[as you can see my R.java is generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dNtM.png)

[but when i display files by package R.java isnt inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH9mi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Actually just needed to update my Android Studio to last version.

Answer (score 0):

try file->invalidate caches/Restart. And check correctly  your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You can do this
1) Close project
2) delete from project list from ide
3) import project again

Comment: what do you mean by sequence, no sure get it ? 
i made it the right order i guess as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Please try following methods

1. Right click on R where error come. Here an option come yo import static R file from current package `or` press alt+enter keys Here also an option come yo import static R file from current package
2. The right side of Android Studio there is `source tree of projec`t. Select `Project` instead of `Android` from source tree options

Now delete the `.idea` and `.gradle` files/folders of project. After that rebuild your project, if rebuild the project does not working then restart the Android Studio.

I hope its work for you.

Comment: Well, thx for the answer, I stil get my issue. actually, when i try to `import my.package.X` android studio suggest me only class from my package and none of my resources (drawable, layout...) 
I still tried to remove `.idea`, and `.gradle` then rebuild, but I still cant import my package.